# How to create new emulator of specif android version in xamarin 5.5.3?

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using xamarin studio for create android application.

first i am open emulator like MonoForAndroid_API_12 from manage android windows and in my project is target framwork 4.4(kit kat) version of android and then finally i am run application but studio give me error **"Running this project requires an Android device with API 19 or above.To run this project, either plug in a compatible device, add a compatible virtual device, or target a lower API level in your project settings."**

Now i am create one sample helloworld application in xamarin studio then i am try to open emulator manager but it seems different version of android application. so i want to create a new emulator manager so i have goto tools and click on manage android device and open new window. there is two emulator but its different or older version and in this window one option like create emulator and i have click more time in that button but nothing happening. 
so please tell me how to create a new emulator?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the AVD manager tool to create a new image for your emalator, make sure to set the API support to 19 (or higher) to fit your needs.

The 2 AVD images that are currently configured are not compliant with the version you need.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/configure_emulator/

Comment: hello @Booger i have try to open AVD Manager from strat menu. but when i have try to open this is open only one second and then close.

Comment: And i have see your link here first step is " Xamarin Studio, the AVD Manager can be launched directly by selecting Tools > Open Android Emulator Manager... from the menu bar". and i have try to find but there is no open for open adnroid emulator manage in my xamarin studio.

Comment: Try to open it from the command line: locate the "monitor" executable in your Android install path